# In Bulgaria with an invalid Schengen Visa. Have flight back home from Czech Republic, what should I do?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights

I have a friend who is in Europe. He went there for a conference that takes place in Czech Republic and another event that takes place in Bulgaria. He flew into Helsinki from Singapore and took another flight to Bulgaria.

Between switching flights from Helsinki to Bulgaria the people at immigration gave him the exit stamp. He thought he had a multiple entry visa but as it turns out he had only a single entry visa.

He has flights from Czech Republic to Singapore(home) booked for the 28th of July. Bulgaria allowed him to enter even though his Schengen Visa had the exit stamp.

I suggested that he should go around Europe and visit countries like Bulgaria that allow people with valid Schengen Visas. Take a flight to Prague on the day he flies out to Singapore and not exit the Airport. He is flying by Finair. Can he somehow make the flight out of a European Country(let's say Bulgaria) a connecting flight and not  need a Visa and fly out of Czech Republic using the flight booked earlier? Obviously without exiting the Airport.

I had even suggested him to visit embassies around Sofia but he says after contacting them some of them said that they won't be able to process the visa in Sofia and they can only do so in his home country or country of residence(Singapore). The Netherlands embassy suggested that they can proceed with the Application but will first have to cancel the existing valid Schengen visa.

Comment: Not sure why this old question turned up in "hot network questions list" for me. Anyway, perhaps applying for a Czech national visa would have been a good option instead of trying to get a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it *might* be possible if not flying with luggage:

- Register online for your flight to Singapore.
- Fly from Bulgaria to Czech republic - you will be let out to non-schengen cleared area after your flight.
- Go to your Singapore flight gate and board. You will not be entering Schengen area at any point or pass through passport control.
- You will not be able to check in luggage because that will require going thru passport control.

This assumes you have a direct flight Czech -> Singapore and not e.g. Czech -> Finland -> Singapore. No intra-Schengen legs. If you do, you can try to re-book your flight, e.g. go from Bulgaria to Helsinki directly and there board a Singapore flight without connecting leg.

This also assumes you're missing your Czech event because you're not exiting airport.

This also assumes that Czech airport (Prague?) has cleared non-Schengen transfer area and that there are flights from Bulgaria coming in before Singapore flight is departing, and you're on it.

Comment: By registering online you mean check in Online?

Yes, the flight goes via Helsinki. Will Finair accept the flight if he misses the Prague -> Helsinki link? Will contacting the Airline help?

Can he possibly get a temporary visa just for flying out of Czech Republic?

Comment: @gyani Does he have a single Prague-Helsinki-Singapore ticket?

Comment: Yes, that's a Single Ticket - Finnair

Comment: @gyani Yes he should rebook the ticket to drop the first leg and instead fly to Helsinki from Bulgaria without entering Schengen (via Moscow for example). Keep in mind that skipping the first leg without telling the airline will likely lead the whole trip to be cancelled.

Comment: @alamar Finnair will **not** drop legs, which I learnt the hard way. If you don't Show up for one leg, the rest **will** be cancelled

Comment: @Crazydre what if you call them and ask to change your itinerary?

Comment: @alamar I confirm they won't do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Your friend made a grave mistake somewhere**

Connecting at Helsinki, if the trip from Singapore to Bulgaria was on one ticket, he should **not** have cleared Finnish immigration at all; thus, his Schengen visa should **not** have been "activated"

If it was on separate tickets (meaning luggage had to be collected) then he should in fact have specifically requested a double-entry visa, presenting the itinerary as evidence and noting that it's on separate tickets (meaning luggage has to be collected past immigration).

Unfortunately your friend is completely out of luck regarding the Czech event. Most, if not all, Schengen embassies will not process visas for people not citizens or legal residents of the country of location.

Comment: Can he still fly out of the country without entering Prague?

Comment: @gyani If it's in a single booking, then yes. Means the luggage is checked through and you don't have to clear Immigration if the Airport has a Transit corridor (which Prague does)

Comment: The flight out of Czech Republic --> Helsinki --> Prague is a Single Booking. Can I get a flight from Sofia --> Czech Republic and make the rest of the booking a single booking?

Comment: @gyani That won't work - because he has no valid Schengen visa the airline will not let him board such a flight. Even if you have a connecting ticket, in practice if it's not in the same booking, airport staff will treat Prague as the final destination. He needs a single ticket via Prague to somewhere where he doesn't Need a visa. So, my question is: **what is his nationality**?

Comment: I'm Sorry. He is from Pakistan and resides in Singapore(has a visa that's valid for a couple for a couple of years).

Can I add a leg to an existing booking?

Comment: @gyani Depends on the Airline you've booked the Prague-Helsinki-Singapore ticket with. I just checked, and only Bulgaria air flies from Sofia to Prague. **Not good**, as you then can't book a connecting ticket from there (as all connections with Bulgaria air are in Sofia). This is **not** a good Situation - I'll have to think for a few minutes

Comment: @gyani He has to call the place where he booked Prague-Helsinki-Singapore ***IMMEDIATELY*** and tell them in exact detail about his situation. He needs to say that, because his Schengen visa has been used up due to a mistake, he can no longer reach Prague. He has to be apologetic and pray taht they agree to change the route to a Sofia-Helsinki-Singapore trip (probably for a high fee). If this fails...I hate to say this, but **he will need a completely new ticket all the way from Sofia to Singapore**. The Airport taxes of the booking from Prague can always be refunded, however

Comment: What about him going to another European country that accepts a Schengen visa like Romania and flying to Helsinki/Prague from there via Finnair?

I'll communicate what you just shared with him.

Comment: @gyani No, because Romania, Croatia and the CEFTA states except Serbia require Schengen visas to be multiple or sometimes double-entry. Serbia accepts single visas only if not used, so none of these are an option.

Comment: @gyani And again, getting to Helsinki without a connecting ticket **in the same booking** to Singapore or somewhere visa-free won't be possible. He has to modify the booking (so that he flies from Sofia instead of Prague), or, if not possible, get a completely new ticket like I said.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Guess he'll have to fly back from Sofia. Do you have any comments on the dutch embassy asking him to cancel his visa before applying for another visa? Or is getting a Schengen visa before 28th of July, while in Bulgaria completely out of question?

Comment: @gyani "Do you have any comments on the dutch embassy asking him to cancel his visa before applying for another visa" Shouldn't be necessary given that his visa has been used up. Probably there was a misunderstanding. Of course, if the embassy is willing to issue him a new visa, he can get it - even if it means cancelling the old one (which is now useless anyway). However, this has to be obtained from the Czech, not Dutch, embassy. If the Dutch but not Czech embassy is willing to issue it, he has to fly to Amsterdam, then to Prague and then catch his flight to Helsinki and Singapore

Comment: @gyani Because, although a Schengen visa technically lets you enter anywhere, it has to be applied for through the main Destination Country, or, if there is None, the one of first entry. If not doing this and caught, you could well be refused entry and blacklisted for visa fraud

Comment: He planned on going to Netherlands anyway as he is giving a talk at TU Delft.  He was worried about cancelling the Schengen visa as he would be as that would make him an illegal immigrant(not sure if the right word?) in Bulgaria.

Comment: @gyani He wouldn't be illegally in Bulgaria, as he has a valid and current entry stamp. So if this speech in Delft is before his return flight, tell him to go to the Dutch embassy immediately, do whatever Needs to be done to get a "Dutch" Schengen visa, attaching proof of his speech (he should explain what he'll to do embassy staff and ask what proof they want). Then go to the Netherlands, then fly to Prague and then hop on his Finnair flight

Comment: @gyani If any of the answers satisfies you, please accept it by clicking on the button below the down arrow